# Turn off animations when AppleScript performs instructions

Tags: animation, applescript

programmers!
I wrote a script which parses in “Numbers” a list with the payments in a bank account and matches them with the invoices issued buy the company.Then it fills a table with the matches.
The script works well, but it shows every move it makes in the Numbers-sheets. In the development phase, it was very good.
But now, it is simply very slow, because of these animations. Is there anyway to turn this animations off?
Thank you very much for your help, indeed, friends!
Dragoș

I remember, in programming a macro for Microsoft excel there was an option like application.screenupdating=false

Do you know about something like this?

Comment: If you are scripting the user interface (clicking buttons, selecting menu items, etc), it needs to be active.

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for helping! The thing is I don't script user interfaces. For example, one of my pieces of code deletes the cells of 200 rows in 4 sheets. When the script performs the action, it shows me every cell it deletes, when it is deleting it. That's why it takes forever. I don't need the script to show me how it deletes the cells. Here is the question!

Comment: Here is my code

Comment: tell application "Numbers"
 tell the front document
  repeat with w from 4 to 7
   repeat with r from 1 to 200
    repeat with s from 1 to 10
     tell sheet w
      tell table 1
       tell row r
        if the value of cell s is not missing value then
         set the value of cell s to missing value
        end if
       end tell --row r
      end tell -- sheet w
     end tell -- table 1
    end repeat --s                                   
   end repeat --r
  end repeat --w

Comment: You can edit your post to include the script, that way you can fit more text, use formatting, etc.